# How to implement compilation test in CMake which should fail?

Tags: c++, testing, compilation, compiler-errors, cmake

I'm working on a long integers library as my C++ home assignment and our teacher has provided as an example of its interface usage. Here is a part of this file:

```
void test_conversions() 
{ 
  int ordinary = 42; 
  lint long_int(ordinary); 
  long_int = ordinary; 

  ordinary = static_cast<int>(long_int); // ok 

  std::string s("-15"); 
  lint z(s); 

  z.to_string() == s; // this should be true
} 

void failed_conversions_test() 
{
  int ordinary = 42; 
  std::string str = "-42"; 
  lint x = 5; 

  ordinary = x; // must be compilation error! 
  x = str; // must be compilation error! 
  str = x; // must be compilation error! 
}
```

I want to test this file for compilatibility during building process. As you can see, there should be four tests: one for compilation success (`test_conversions`) and three for each of fails presented in `failed_conversions_test`. I can easily implement compilation success check by adding a stub `int main()` and calling `ADD_TEST` in `CMakeLists.txt`, but how do I tell CMake to compile the remaining three tests and ensure that compilation was unsuccessful?

I was thinking about adding something like 'run custom script which do all the things', but this is very compiler- and platform- dependent and doesn't look like the good way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The [`try_compile`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3atry_compile) command might be what you are looking for.

You can use it to try building a single source file and have the result reported back to CMake:

```
try_compile(COMPILE_SUCCEEDED ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_tests my_test_src.cpp)

if(COMPILE_SUCCEEDED)
  message("Success!")
endif()
```

The motivation behind this feature was to test for compiler features, so it is only going to be executed at CMake configure time, *not* at build time. If you still want the latter, you need to resort to a custom build step with a script.